# How to use the UIWebview with enabled cookies?

Tags: ios, ipad, memory-management, uiwebview, session-cookies

How to use the `UIWebview` with enabled cookies? I am using lot of web apps in my iOS app, each app has their own URL to load their app.

All web apps are displayed with their name and app icon in a `UITableView` (app list). Whenever user tap on app from the app list, we are loading that app in `UIWebview`.

If user again tap on the same app we are loading from cookies not loading from the start.

In this scenario how to use `UIWebview`?

Normally `UIWebview` took lot of memory, if we opened lot of apps memory increased huge.

Please suggest how to use `UIWebview` with effective manner.